# Watch Google Calendar event for changes and updating server-side

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to listen to a Google Calendar event I created using a **watch** request but I have no clue how to get the event details once I get the push notification.

So this is what I have so far, I create the Calendar event using JavaScript (it prompts the user for authorization):

```js
function createEvent(data) {
  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'resource': data
  });

  request.execute(function(event) {
    if (!event.code) {
      openToast('The event was added to your Google Calendar')

      watchEvent(data.id);
    }
  });
}
```

And then I create a **watch** request to get the PUSH notifications:

```js
function watchEvent(eventId) {
  gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
    auth: gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance(),
    resource: {
      id: eventId,
      type: 'web_hook',
      address: webhookUrl
    },
    calendarId: 'primary'
  }).execute(function onWatchCalendarEvent(event) {
    if (event.error) {
      console.error('Error creating event watch webhook', event.error);
    }
  });
}
```

So far so good, this is working OK and I receive a PUSH notification with the `channelID` from which I can get my own internal `meetingId`.

```java
@PostMapping
  public void onCalendarEventUpdate(@RequestHeader(name = "x-goog-channel-id") String channelId,
      @RequestHeader(name = "x-goog-resource-state") String resourceState) {
    
    log.info("Received Google Calendar event update notification: " + resourceState);

    // only when the event is modified google posts the resource state as "exists"
    // (what kind of name is that anyway?)
    if (resourceState.equals("exists")) {

      // get the meeting ID from the channel ID
      Long meetingId = findMeetingIdFromChannelId(channelId);
  
      calendarService.updateMeeting(meetingsService.findById(meetingId));
    }
  }
```

I've read the docs for [Authorizing Requests](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth), [PUSH Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) and [Java API Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java) but they all prompt for the user authorization. Since this PUSH notification is happening asynchronously how am I supposed to get the updated event details? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have the calendar and event id (e.g. from the notification you get from Google that you receive and parse at your webhookUrl location), you can make calendar api calls to get all the event details:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get

Comment: Which one is the event ID in the notification by Google?